# Use a variables in a other variables name with exec()

Tags: python, exec

I am programming a bot for a game. I wanted to use a variable in a variables name. I wrote an simplified code to check my function and it worked. Then in put my code in the real bot and it is just nor working.
The Code has a class which is showing the player. The bot is getting imported out of another file. This is working i have tried it already.

I searched a lot in the internet, the best solution for me was exec(). But if there is an better i will take it ?

```py
this is the simple code
p1_l=[1,2,3,4,5]
p2_l=[6,7,8,9,10]
p3_l=[11,12,13,14,15]
p4_l=[16,17,18,19,20]
#these are the known lists

a="p1"
#a is deciding if we are going to work with list 1,2,3 or 4
#the value of a is random

b=str(a)+"_l"
#b is now "list_1"

#now i have an function foo()
def foo(a):
    return a
#this functions is only an simple example
#now i want to use my b in this function
#i only know one possible way with exec()

exec("r=foo({})".format(b))
print(r)

#but this is not working
```

that is the real code

```py
#----------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------

def get_all_cards():
    RANK_ORDER_NUM = '34567890JQKA2'
    SUIT_ORDER_NUM = 'DCHS'
    all_cards=[]
    for i in RANK_ORDER_NUM:
        for a in SUIT_ORDER_NUM:
            all_cards.append(i+a)
    return all_cards

#----------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------

def shuffle_all_cards(cards_list):
    import random
    random.shuffle(cards_list)
    return cards_list

#----------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------

def give_players_cards(shuffled_cards):
    p1_cards=shuffled_cards[0:12]
    p2_cards=shuffled_cards[13:26]
    p3_cards=shuffled_cards[27:39]
    p4_cards=shuffled_cards[40:]
    return p1_cards,p2_cards,p3_cards,p4_cards

#----------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------

class Player():
    def __init__(self,cards,version):
        self.version=version
        self.cards=cards

    def play(self, hand, is_start_of_round, play_to_beat, round_history, player_no, hand_sizes, scores, round_no):
        play_modul = __import__("Week_1_Bot_v"+str(self.version))
        played_card = play_modul.play(hand, is_start_of_round, play_to_beat, round_history, player_no, hand_sizes, scores, round_no)
        return played_card

#----------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------

def game(version_p1, version_p2, version_p3, version_p4):
    all_cards=get_all_cards()
    #print(all_cards)
    shuffeled_cards=shuffle_all_cards(all_cards)
    #print(shuffeled_cards)
    p1_start_hand,p2_start_hand,p3_start_hand,p4_start_hand=give_players_cards(shuffeled_cards)
    import random
    player_order=["player1","player1","player3","player4"]
    player_order_in_game=random.shuffle(player_order)
    p1 = Player(p1_start_hand,2)
    p2 = Player(p2_start_hand,2)
    p3 = Player(p3_start_hand,2)
    p4 = Player(p4_start_hand,2)
    p1_hand=p1_start_hand
    p2_hand=p2_start_hand
    p3_hand=p3_start_hand
    p4_hand=p4_start_hand
    if ("3D" in p1_hand):
        player_beginning="p1"
    if ("3D" in p2_hand):
        player_beginning="p2"
    if ("3D" in p3_hand):
        player_beginning="p3"
    if ("3D" in p4_hand):
        player_beginning="p4"


    #print(player_beginning)
    #print(p1_hand,p2_hand,p3_hand,p4_hand)
    """
    The parameters to this function are:
    * `hand`: A list of card strings that are the card(s) in your hand.
    * `is_start_of_round`: A Boolean that indicates whether or not the `play` function is being asked to make the first play of a round.
    * `play_to_beat`: The current best play of the trick. If no such play exists (you are the first play in the trick), this will be an empty list.
    * `round_history`: A list of *trick_history* entries.
        A *trick_history* entry is a list of *trick_play* entries.
        Each *trick_play* entry is a `(player_no, play)` 2-tuple, where `player_no` is an integer between 0 and 3 (inclusive) indicating which player made the play, and `play` is the play that said player made, which will be a list of card strings.
    * `player_no`: An integer between 0 and 3 (inclusive) indicating which player number you are in the game.
    * `hand_sizes`: A 4-tuple of integers representing the number of cards each player has in their hand, in player number order. 
    * `scores`: A 4-tuple of integers representing the score of each player at the start of this round, in player number order.
    * `round_no`: An integer between 0 and 9 (inclusive) indicating which round number is currently being played.

    This function should return an empty list (`[]`) to indicate a pass (see "Playing a Round"), or a list of card strings, indicating that you want to play these cards to the table as a valid play.
    """
    is_start_of_round=True
    play_to_beat=[]
    round_history=[]
    hand_sizes=[13,13,13,13]
    scores=[0,0,0,0]
    rounds_no=0

    #play1_test = p3.play( p3_hand , is_start_of_round , play_to_beat , round_history , 2 , hand_sizes , scores , rounds_no)
    #play1_test = p3.play(['5H', '4D', '4H', '7D', '8D', '8H', '0D', '0C', 'JH', 'QC', 'QS', 'KH', 'AS'], False, ["6H"], [[]], 0, [13, 13, 13, 13], [0, 0, 0, 0], 0)
    #print(play1_test) 

    #play1_0=0
    b=str(player_beginning) + "_hand"
    print(b)
    def foo(a):
        return a
    r="foo({})".format(b)
    #print(r)










    #print("play1_0" + "=" + player_beginning + ".play([" + player_beginning + "_hand" + "]," + str(is_start_of_round) + "," + str(play_to_beat) + "," + "[" + str(round_history) + "]" + "," + str(int(player_beginning[1])-1) + "," + str(hand_sizes) + "," + str(scores) + "," + str(rounds_no) + ")")
    #exec("play1_0" + "=" + player_beginning + ".play([" + player_beginning + "_hand" + "]," + str(is_start_of_round) + "," + str(play_to_beat) + "," + str(round_history) + "," + str(int(player_beginning[1])-1) + "," + str(hand_sizes) + "," + str(scores) + "," + str(rounds_no) + ")")
    #print(play1_0)


game(2,2,2,2)
```

The problem is in the real code my variable "r" is not defined. So the exec() function is not defining the "r" as one of the p1_hand....lists.

I hope it is understandable.
Thank You

Niklas

Answer (score 0):

For the example you have in your test code, I would use a dictionary of lists instead:

```py
my_dict = {"p1": [elem1, elem2], "p2":[elem3, elem4], ...}
```

To access it you can do:

```py
player = "p1"
player_list = my_dict[player]
```